# Angular Material Theme

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am currently using Angular 8 with Angular Material. My question is that 
my theme is loaded on the network tab, but it's not applying. Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: Have u added @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; in styles.css/scss

Comment: Can you please share html code and file where you have added theme ?